# How to determine integrals with the substitution method?

Tags: integration

I am trying to learn the substitution method for solving integrals. I have these two examples but I don't know how to solve these:

$$\int \frac{3x^3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+1}}dx$$

and

$$\int \frac{x}{({x^2+1})^6}dx$$

Thanks for every advance

Comment: The derivative of $x^4+1$ is (basically) sitting on top. so let $u=x^4+1$. The derivative of $x^2+1$ is basically sitting on top. So let $u=x^2+1$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

In the First case $\displaystyle x^4+1=u\implies4x^3\ dx=du$

and in the Second $\displaystyle x^2+1=v\implies2x\ dx=dv$